# Jtogglebutton setting background dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, timertask, jtogglebutton

i have a problem with setting background color of Jtogglebutton dynamically. I want Jtogglebutton blink like a led, on and off at a decised time, like 500ms.  I tried to override paint and paintComponent method too. But couldn't succeed either. I'm stuck. Here is my code thanks for help.

Led class:

```
public class Led extends JToggleButton {
private Color okColor = Color.GREEN;
private Color notOkColor = Color.RED;
private static int BLINK_FREQUENCY=500;

public Led() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
    timer.start();
}

Timer timer=new Timer(BLINK_FREQUENCY, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setBackground(okColor);
            System.out.println("ok");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(BLINK_FREQUENCY);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            setBackground(notOkColor);
            System.out.println("notok");
    }
});
```

}

MainFrame Class:

```
public class MainFrame {

private JFrame frame;
private Led led;
private JPanel panel;

public MainFrame() {
    initializeComponents();
}

private void initializeComponents() {
    frame = new JFrame("Blinking Led");
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    {
        panel = new JPanel();
        led = new Led();
        panel.add(led);
        frame.add(panel);
    }

}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    frame.setVisible(visible);
}
```

}

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand right, you want the color to switch every 500 ms or you want the state of the button to switch and then trigger the color switch?

Comment: I want to switch color of button every 500ms. State is not important.

Comment: Why would you `sleep` inside action listener?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't see the point in using the Timer class but just a simple thread should work

```
public Led() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
    thread.start();
}

Thread  thread  = new Thread(() -> {
                    while (true) {
                        if (getBackground().equals(notOkColor)) {
                            setBackground(okColor);
                        } else {
                            setBackground(notOkColor);
                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(BLINK_FREQUENCY);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: :) Thanks. it helped me a lot. Do you have any idea to make it with paint method?

Comment: @Antoniossss No there is absolutely no point in using a class that provides you with an ActionListener and ActionEvent that you won't ever use in your code. The correct way is to manually invoke revalidate() and repaint() on EDT using SwingUtils.invokeLater() but in this case not even that is required.

Comment: @f.mike You want to update the background from inside the paint() method of your other class, MainFrame?

Comment: i tried both. updating inside of Led and MainFrame. No matter how for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost done:

```
    Timer timer=new Timer(BLINK_FREQUENCY, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          setBackgroundColor(getBackgroundColor()==okColor ? noOkColor:okColor);
    }
    });

timer.start();
```